# Calculate X Y Z angles from two Quaternions has a lot of noise in Y axis (theta)

Tags: python, quaternions, angle

I'm trying to calculate the angle in three axes (x=phi, y=theta, z=psi) in python and put the results in a graph from two quaternions given.

Here my code to calculate those angles:

```
 q_upper = pyq.Quaternion(q1[0], q1[1], q1[2], q1[3])
 q_lower = pyq.Quaternion(q2[0], q2[1], q2[2], q2[3])

 qd = q_upper.conjugate * q_lower
 phi = math.atan2(2 * (qd.w * qd.x + qd.y * qd.z), 1 - 2 * (qd.x ** 2 + qd.y ** 2))
 theta = math.asin(2 * (qd.w * qd.y - qd.z * qd.x))
 psi = math.atan2(2 * (qd.w * qd.z + qd.x * qd.y), 1 - 2 * (qd.y ** 2 + qd.z ** 2))
```

I use a pyquaternion module for work with quaterions (great module for this) and after calculate the difference orientation from two quaternions I only convert from quaternion to X, Y, Z Euler Angles.

All is good for X and Z orientations. But with Y axis a obtain only data until 90º and a lot of noise in the other graphs.

Here a sample for each axes:

For X it obtains right angles for z and z without changes:

[image: Movement over X]

After it obtains right angle for z:

[image]

And the problem with calculating y axis with a lot of noise in other axis:

[image]

I want to ask for if this formulas are right or maybe are the magnetic fields. I appreciate some hint or advice about formulas or whetever.

Thanks a lot
Have a nice day

Comment: There is a mistake. The second graph attached is wrong. I can't put images but the right second graph has the variation of angle in the Z axis, not in Y axis like wrong image. Hope this help for my question.

Comment: I assume for y axis (pitch rotation) has gimbal lock. But why these noises in the other axis when x and z haven't noises in the other axes?